# how to rename multiple sub directories of a parent folder with a script?

Tags: batch-file, command

I have parent folder with several sub directories which contain folders named the same to be renamed to the same name. I would like place a script at the parent folder that will traverse through the subfolders and rename directories according to a match. For instance in each folder with a folder name Foo rename it to Apple.

the script I have not working is

```
FOR /D %%D IN (*.*) DO (
    REN "Foo"   "Apple"
    REN "Bar" "Banana"
    REN "Baz"  "Mango"
)
```

inside the for loop that script is trying to rename files. If I place the lines below in a .cmd file it will rename folders

```
REN "Foo" "Apple"
```

I would like to place the script in the parent folder and have it search through the sub folders and rename all the Foo folders to Apple, all the Bar folders to Banana, and all the Baz folders to Mango

**Current Folder Tree:**

```
|  Parent Folder
|  |--Sub Folder 1
|  |  |--Foo
|  |  |--Bar
|  |  |--Baz
|  |--Sub Folder 2
|  |  |--Foo
|  |  |--Bar
|  |  |--Baz
|  |--Sub Folder 3
|  |  |--Foo
|  |  |--Bar
|  |  |--Baz
```

**Renamed Folder Tree would be:**

```
|  Parent Folder
|  |--Sub Folder 1
|  |  |--Apple
|  |  |--Banana
|  |  |--Mango
|  |--Sub Folder 2
|  |  |--Apple
|  |  |--Banana
|  |  |--Mango
|  |--Sub Folder 3
|  |  |--Apple
|  |  |--Banana
|  |  |--Mango
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[untested]

```
for /d /r %%e in (*.*) do (
 echo ren "%%e\Foo" "Apple" 2>nul
 echo ren "%%e\Bar" "Banana" 2>nul
 ...
)
```

The `ren` commands are `echo`ed to the console for verification purposes.

If the resultant list is what you want to do, remove the `echo` keywords to activate the rename.

The `2>nul` should suppress error messages (like if `Foo` does not exist)

Comment: that still does not go inside the sub folders - it returns error of "The system cannot find the specified file"  what is the purpose of %%~dp in front of the current folder name?

Comment: Should have been `%%e\foo` - `%%e` would be the name of each directory in the subtree, so `%%e\foo` would be the full name of the directory `foo` .  If you want to run it against the current directory as well as the subdirectories, you'd also need to run `for %%e in (.) do (the lines within parentheses)`

Comment: works perfectly now thanks @Magoo just what I was looking for